# Can You Get Project Startdate from Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to query the Azure Devops REST API to see when a project first came into existence and, perhaps, who created it. I'm using the link below and my results do match the documentation which, unfortunately, doesn't include create date. Is there any other ways to query AzDo REST API to get this data?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get%20project%20properties?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no rest api to get the start date of project. The start date property is not included in the returned results of [Get Project Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#definitions).

This issue has been reported to Microsoft develop team. You can vote up [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/907560/how-to-get-project-creation-date-in-azure-devops.html) or [submit a new feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click Suggest a feature and choose Azure Devops).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. At the time that answer was made, you query the project history and get all the revisions and states from the beginning.

Unfortunately, somewhere between then and now, MS broke the API call, but the document still exists.

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/projects/%7BprojectId%7D)?
includeHistory=true&api-version=7.1-preview.4